# Searching for "On Hold" questions?

Tags: support

The search feature allows you to search for a question based on status. Mainly closed, migrated, or wiki. Is there the same for questions put on hold?

Answer (score 3):

Questions "On Hold" are still fundamentally "Closed", and you search for them in the same way. For example:

`closed:yes` gives you the [following results](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed:1).

Comment: Ah, sort by newest. It defaults to sort by relevance. That answers that.